# How to add property to mocked module jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a module which is generated by webpack at build time called config.

```
// webpack.config.js
let devConfig = {url: 'https://localhost'}
...
externals: {
    'config': JSON.stringify(devConfig),
},
```

I import and ise it like;

```
import config from 'config'
console.log(config.url)
```

How can I mock this module, and give the url during the test?

I've tried following. It's making config object avaliable but not url.

```
// __mocks__/config.js
jest.mock('config', ()=>({url: 'https://localhost'}), {virtual: true})
```

How can I add url propery to mocked module?

Thank you.

---

Note: I need url since I will need it when using nock.

Comment: Propery == property?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is;

Looks like something elese was preventing me.

`jest.mock("Config", ()=> ({url: 'https://localhost'}), {virtual: true});`